# QGIS layout, split grid coordinates from A to Z

Tags: qgis, layouts, grids-graticules

I have been using the layout manager to make coordinates for this map. I am fairly new to QGIS so my knowledge is a little limited on how to do this.

I have used this code

```
    if ( @grid_axis = 'y' ,
substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', (@grid_number - 1.105) / 1.105 + 1.105, 1)
,
ceil((y_max(@map_extent ) - @grid_number) + 50 )
)
```

I am quite confused, as I used this on another map, and the alphabet numbers do not repeat. How can I improve this code or stop the letters from repeating?

[image]

Comment: Where do you use this formula, and where did you get it from ? The fixed parameters like 50 and 1.105 are tightly related to the coordinate width/height of the framed map so they can't work seamlessly for any map.

Comment: I just used it generate the code, i assumed it would work on this map to. Sorry im new. I can get it to only 2 characters now. 

if ( @grid_axis = 'y' ,
substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', (@grid_number - 1) % 26 + 1, 1)
,
ceil((y_max(@map_extent ) - @grid_number) + 50 )
)

Comment: Do you want to split the height in 26  lines named A to Z ?

Comment: Yes 
I also tried this but I still get repeating alphabets characters and i seem to unable to make an dic to validate them. 

if ( @grid_axis = 'y' ,
substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', floor((@grid_number - 1) / 26) * 26 + (@grid_number - 1) % 26 + 1, 1)
,
ceil((y_max(@map_extent ) - @grid_number) + 50 )
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the vertical axis to be split in 26 lines, from A to Z, whatever the map height, you can do the following:

Set the `Y interval` to `@map_extent_height/26` to split the hight in 26 cells:

[image]

Then set the `Y Offset` to `y_min(@map_extent)%(@map_extent_height/26)+0.0001` to have the first cell start right above the bottom:

[image]

Then use this formula in the `Coordinate Format (Custom)`:

```
if ( @grid_axis = 'y' ,
substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
round((@grid_number-y_min(@map_extent))/@map_extent_height*26)+1,1)
,
'1')
```

and set the Coordinates to be layed 'above tick'

[image]

Here you go for the vertical axis, you can do something similar for the horizontal axis
[image]

It handles scale change / changing the Map item automatically:
[image]

Comment: i tried this but now all i get from Y is Z repeated.  Still fairly confused why this wont work . Please note im using CM to measure the invernals not map units. Does that make a difference?

Ps I appreciate the effort given for the answer, thank you.

Comment: Can't you use Map units ?

Comment: @map_extent dimension are not in centimeters so I don't think cm can work

Comment: @Thanks your answer helped me find my solution. I had the wrong values in my intervals and so that's why it was duplicating the alphabet characters. Thanks again